# How to derive $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}} $?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to derive $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}} $?

My first thought is l'Hôpital's rule. So $ x^{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}} =e^{\ln x\sin{\frac{1}{x}} }$. Now to compute $\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln x\sin{\frac{1}{x}} =\lim_{x\to \infty}-\ln \frac1x\sin{\frac{1}{x}} $, let $y=\frac1x,$ we get  $\lim_{y\to 0}-\frac{\frac{\sin y}{y}}{\frac{1}{y\ln y}}$. For the bottom, I consider write it as $\frac{\frac1y}{\ln y}$ using l'Hôpital's rule we get $\lim_{y\to 0}-\frac{1}{y}$, now I am stuck because I don't know if the $y$ approaches from left or right.

Could someone help?

Comment: You set y=1/x and x goes to infinity so y decreases to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply L'Hospital's rule after some steps $$\lim _{ x\to \infty  } x^{ \sin { \frac { 1 }{ x }  }  }=\lim _{ x\to \infty  } e^{ \sin { \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { x }  }  }=e^{ \lim _{ x\to \infty  } \frac { \sin { \frac { 1 }{ x }  }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  } \frac { \ln { x }  }{ x }  }=e^{ \lim _{ x\to \infty  } \frac { \ln { x }  }{ x }  }\overset { L'Hospital }{ = } { e }^{ \lim _{ x\to \infty  } \frac { 1 }{ x }  }=1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Observe that

$$\sin\frac1x\log x=\frac{\sin\frac1x}{\frac1x}\cdot\frac{\log x}x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}1\cdot0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital's rule is *not* the α and ω of limits calculations, and it can lead to errors if it's not applied in a correct way.

This being said, you can use *equivalents*. First note it is enough to find the limit of the logarithm $\; \sin \frac1x \ln x$. Set $u=\frac1x$. Then you get
$$\sin\frac1x\ln x=-\sin u\ln u\sim_0 -u\ln u\xrightarrow[u\to 0]{}0.$$
Thus the required limit is $1$.